# What does "uber-word" mean in particular context (see body of question)?

Tags: meaning, neologisms, derivational-morphology

### What does *uber-word* mean in the following context?

This question came up at [Is "act like a mensch" too localized for ELU readers (U.S. and/or British English)?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/272481/is-act-like-a-mensch-too-localized-for-elu-readers-u-s-and-or-british-englis)

*Uber-word* came up in this exchange:

> English has always welcomed foreign jargon; it gives the locals
> something new to grumble at.
>
> You mean there’s no angst that imports from foreign jargon become
> uber-words?

What I’ve tried so far: I looked up the definition of *uber*, and I asked my German spouse.

Comment: First and foremost note that this is a joke: *uber* is a loan word. Second: look up *ubermensche*, and what Nietszche's theories predicted they would do.

Comment: _Uber_- is a new libfix in American English at any rate. It comes from German _über_, meaning 'over', which came into English as _das Übermensch_ 'Superman' from Nietzsche's writings. English doesn't have the right vowels to say _über_, especially capitalized, but the recent advent of the ride-sharing Uber company has made it more popular with /u/ instead of /ü/. In this sense _uber_ means 'popular, famous, stylish, important'.

Comment: @DanBron - I could tell it was a funny, but I wasn't able to appreciate the joke.  By the way, I am able to use the preposition über in a (simple) sentence in German (from functioning in family life with a German spouse two polyglot children, and a monolingual mother-in-law).

Comment: @JohnLawler - So is *uber-word* kind of like a meme?

Comment: @aparente001 The *ubermensche* (according to Nietzsche) were supposed to take over the world, overthrowing regular men. Thus (presumably) the implication is native speakers would fear uber-words from regular (English) words. It's a play on *uber* being a loanword, a pun playing on the fact the question was about *mensche*, and the concept of *ubermensche*.

Comment: @DanBron - Thanks -- now that's what I would call Answer material!

Comment: @DanBron You mean *Übermensche*, doncha now? :)

Comment: @tchrist - I think the singular would be Übermensch and the plural Übermenschen....

Comment: I really think that should have been closed. The word was admittedly invented by an internet commenter. Only that person can answer this question and there is no use for any future reader in this question.

Comment: @Helmar - What I'm asking is, how do people take it?  What do people think it means when they see it?  I am having trouble figuring it out, perhaps because I speak some (limited) German, and I suspect I'm taking the prefix too literally.  No one has yet answered the clarifying questions in the bounty statement yet.

Comment: @aparente001 that's the problem, it's a prime example of being opinion based.

Comment: @Helmar - My impression is that everybody else understood the invented word well enough, it was just me who found it confusing, because of my limited knowledge of German.  I suspect *uber* and *über* may be somewhat false cognates.  Let me ask you this:  did the meaning seem clear to you when you read it, or are you still scratching your head about this as much as I am?

Comment: @aparente001 the likely problem is that there is nothing indicating that everyone understood it the same way. Bad multilingual puns by internet commenters do not have to make sense or result in a commonly understood meaning.

Comment: @Helmar - Would you be so kind as to share the understanding that you formed?

Comment: Obviously, it's a word that arrives via jitney taxi.

Comment: Came across a fun modern German usage of "über" at https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/multi-web-search/reviews/: "Danke kameraden das addon ist ÜBER! Rated 5 out of 5 stars; your search can end here as this is one if not the best of the best!" Clearly, this native German speaker is using "über" to mean *super, fantastic*, with absolutely no connotation of evil or anything remotely negative.

Comment: @aparente001 that's actually a internet pun on the English usage. That is not general German usage ;)

Comment: Another bounty? What's for? What happened to the previous bounty?

Comment: @JOSH - I'm sorry, I missed the deadline the first time around.  Please see http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/9676/did-i-miss-the-bounty-deadline-and-if-so-is-there-any-way-of-manually-awarding

Comment: I see, be careful not to miss it again :)

Comment: @JOSH - The deadline won't be so tight this time.  The answer I accepted came in at the last minute.

Comment: @aparente001 I think you should award it while you still can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to know exactly what the commentator meant without asking him or her, but there are several possibilities. An uber-word could be:

1. a superlative word (which was how I initially understood it)
2. a trendy word (that pushes out the native one for a while)
3. a "cuckoo" word that usurps all native words

It's this last one that I'm leaning towards at the moment, as this is how the taxi firm operates, and this is the most well known use of the word uber at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/uber), it means **"Super; high-level; high-ranking"**. I believe "uber" or "über" has become synonym of "super", as [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%9Cber) explains:

> "One of the first popular modern uses of the word as a synonym in
>   English for super was a *Saturday Night Live* TV sketch in 1979. The
>   sketch, *What if?*, pondered the notion of what if the comic book hero
>   Superman had landed in Nazi Germany when he first came from Krypton.
>   Rather than being called **Superman**, he took the name of **Übermann**."

There are some interesting definitions and theories on the origin of "uber" in [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=uber), but no authoritative sources to back them up. In any case, they also tend to support the idea that "uber" is used as a synonym of "super," even in the context you give.

Answer (score 1):

In a comment, John Lawler answered:

> *Uber*- is a new libfix in American English at any rate. It comes from German *über*, meaning ‘over’, which came into English as *das Übermensch* ‘Superman’ from Nietzsche's writings.
>
> English doesn't have the right vowels to say *über*, especially capitalized, but the recent advent of the ride-sharing Uber company has made it more popular [spelled with] with /u/ instead of /ü/.
>
> In this sense *uber* means ‘popular, famous, stylish, important’.

Comment: Does it mean a new word, or a predator word? Is it an interloper, or a super-word?  What is the speaker's attitude toward the term he's describing as an uber-word?

Comment: Furthermore the commenter himself says: "I made up the combination uber-word, but the etymological root is of course [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%9Cber#In_English)"

Comment: @aparente001 - I don't think it is possible to know exactly what the commentator meant without asking him or her, but there are several possibilities: uber-words are just super words (which was how I initially understood it), trendy words (that push out the native one for a while), or "cuckoo" words that usurp all native words. It's this last one that I'm leaning towards at the moment, as this is how the taxi firm operates, and this is now the most famous use of the word uber at the moment!

Comment: @JonLarby - This is helpful.  Would you mind moving it to an Answer?

Answer (score 0):

The following extract from ***[The Boston Globe](https://www.bostonglobe.com/ideas/2014/07/26/the-long-strange-journey-uber/6DFRmI3xcKJdXUtljsDktO/story.html)*** traces the origin  and  explains the meaning and usage of "uber" in the English language and how it changed in recent decades.  Its current usage is essentially as a synonym  and an extension of "super."