# Genderless version of "Better man than I"

Tags: phrase-requests

I (a woman) frequently find myself wanting to reply to a statement with the phrase "You're a better man than I."

If I say this to a man though, it sounds absurd, and to a woman, potentially insulting. Is there a genderless equivalent for this phrase? The obvious choice, "a better person than I", seems to have a quite different connotation.

E.g. someone says to me, "I always eat my vegetables, and run a marathon every Tuesday," to which I reply, "You're a __________________ than I, " or "You're more _____________ than I."

Comment: You’re more dedicated than I am.

Comment: I see no problems with the connotations of "You're a better person than I." The context makes it clear you're *not* talking specifically about moral virtues. An alternative is "You're better than me."

Comment: *man* : a human being of either sex; a person.

Comment: What's wrong with "You're a better person than I am"?  I've heard that, or statements very much similar, a number of times.

Comment: You're a better carbon based life form than I.

Comment: @Mazura That particular dictionary definition is becoming out of date.

Comment: In my experience the phrase is often used to, and by, women as it is a quotation from Kipling.

Comment: @CandiedOrange Silicon life forms have feelings t...oh wait. Never mind.

Comment: Silenus said all that needs to be said to answer the specific question.

Since - sorry, Mitch - Mazura is quite right might we encourage everyone to notice the corollary?

Must we stick with the complaint that “man” means either “male” or “human being” and therefore “woman” is somehow derogatory?

Should we not rather believe that as “man” means either “male” or “human being” so “woman” is a mark of distinction; not simply difference, but excellence?

Comment: You can say "man" between female friends if it's clear you're quoting/referencing something. Just as you can say "smarter than the average bear" or other animal idioms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're a better *mensch* than I.

You're a better *soul* than I.

Alternatively:

You've got more _______ than I, for example

You've got more *heart* than I.

You've got more *commitment* than I.

You've got better *discipline* than I.

Comment: Yes, but isn't the word 'mensch' gender-specific? Is there a female equivalent in Yiddish?

Comment: You've got more 'cojones' than I.

Comment: @PeterPoint - No, it's not gender specific at all.  It means "human", but I chose it because it's one syllable instead of two, and in the original "You're a better man than I," *man* is only one syllable.  Somewhat related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/272481/is-act-like-a-mensch-too-localized-for-elu-readers-u-s-and-or-british-englis/272488

Comment: Re your second comment: People in the U.S. often use vulgar terms from other languages, thinking that since the term isn't English, others won't be offended by the vulgarity.  I disapprove of that practice.  (You're not alone in doing it.)

Comment: Re my second comment: Sincere apologies if this offended your own sensibilities or, for that matter, those of any of our numerous American cousins on site. Evidently we in the UK have a long way to go in the use of language, Anglo or otherwise. The OED lists that word as meaning "courage; guts", distinguishing it from its "vulgar" use and meaning in North America. Wait a minute: America's pukka dictionary, Merriam-Webster online, defines it first-on-the list as, "Boldness or courage needed to do something".  The "other" meaning is listed separately thereafter, in the alternative.

Comment: @PeterPoint - As I said, you're not alone.  I think if you translate it literally and try to use it in a sentence over coffee with your boss, you'll see what I mean.

Answer (score 3):

In most cases, people are pretty comfortable accepting "man" as meaning "human". That particular phrase isn't likely to see much use in a formal setting either, so the subtleties of pronoun-based sexism aren't likely to come up through its appropriate use. Otherwise...

You're a better person than I.

Or

You're a better [genderless or appropriate title] than I.
(*Example:* "You're a better vegetarian than I.")

In general conversation, person can stand in for man in almost all cases. It just sounds awkward when used in a title. (*Example:* Police-Person)

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit off the beaten path, but I'll try it because I think it would work well. It sidesteps the gender issues of *man* and the banality of *person*, while having a humorous aspect. How about *creature*?

> You're a better *creature* than I.

From Merriam-Webster:

> [*creature*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/creature): an
>   animal of any type

Try it, you might like it!

Comment: I actually like that a lot more than the answer I gave!

Comment: @Richard Kayser  Salutations! I like wandering off the beaten path, what?  "Tho' I've belted and flayed you, by the living Gawd that made you, your'e a better man than I am, Gunga Din!"  From Rudyard Kipling's poem, 'Gunga Din'.

Comment: @PeterPoint Salutations! Good to hear from you. Thanks for the Gunga Din. Much appreciated. "Is man merely a mistake of Gawd's? Or Gawd merely a mistake of man's?" Nietzsche.

Comment: @RichardKayser You're asking me? This is beyond my ken. It's a pity that the Patron Saint of Atheists, the late Christopher Hitchins, is no longer here to enter the philosophical debate of God vs Man and vice-versa. I remain an unapologetic Marxist on all things of that kind. Yes, dear old Groucho influenced my thinking in more ways than anyone can possibly imagine.

Comment: @PeterPoint Your response bams my boozles!

Comment: I don't really like this answer - mainly because "creature" in reference to humans normally carries connotations of peculiarity (which doesn't fit the context).

Answer (score 0):

I agree.  "You're a better person than I" is often used.
Why not "You're a better woman than I" when speaking to a woman?

Answer (score 0):

The entire quote is "You're a better man than I, Gunga Din." By keeping the quote intact, it's directed at Gunga Din and not the person in front of you, and (hopefully) given its historical validity, nobody  will be offended

Comment: They might not go for the "Though I've belted you and flayed you, / By the living Gawd that made you" buildup to the quoted language from the original poem, however.

Comment: As if you'd include that part.